# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no fxcore2 in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I get the following exception:
**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no fxcore2 in java.library.path**
I've added the fxcore2.jar to building path and put it under WEB-INFO->lib folder.
They include instructions suggesting :
Add fxcore2.jar to the libraries
In NetBeans: Libraries->Add JAR/Folder
In Eclipse: Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries tab->Add External JARs
Add: C:\Program Files\Candleworks\ForexConnectAPI\bin\java\fxcore2.jar

Change working directory
In Netbeans: Run->Working Directory
In Eclipse: Project->Properties->Run/Debug Settings->New->(Select Configuration Type)->Main tab (Pick the main class)->Arguments tab->Working Directory (click "Other")
Add: C:\Program Files\Candleworks\ForexConnectAPI\bin

Send java.library.path to Java VM
In Netbeans: Project->Properties->Run->VM options
In Eclipse: Project->Properties->Run/Debug Settings->(pick up configuration you just created)->Arguments tab->VM arguments
Add: -Djava.library.path=.;./java (path for Windows)

Add namespace com.fxcore2 to your project:
import com.fxcore2.*;

How i can include the jar to dynamic web project and get rid of the exception ?

Thanks